# Proof for trick to multiply fast

Tags: proof-explanation, alternative-proof

lets say we want to multiply 78*94

we multiply the first number by the third  then we multiply the second by the fourth we get 6332 next we multiply 2nd and 3d + 1st and 4th we get 100 we add this to our previus number shifted 1 to the left we get :

7332

$$7*9 = 63$$
$$8*4 = 32$$
$$n = 6332 +1000$$
is there any proof for this and how can this be done with bigger numbers?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're doing. You say the third number but there are only two numbers given. I can't reproduce $6332$ from what you've said here.

Comment: The proof is really as simple as this: if $a,b,c,d$ are digits, then our two numbers are $10a+b$ and $10c+d$, and so: $(10a+b)(10c+d)=(100ac+bd)+10(ad+bc)$. The first term $100ab+cd$ is what you get when you paste $ab$ shifted twice to $cd$ (put a leading zero in front of $cd$ if needed), whereas the second term $10(ad+bc)$ is the result $ad+bc$ shifted once.

Comment: @CyclotomicField They are multiplying the first digits $7\times 9=63$ and the last digits $8\times 4=32$ and pasting the two results to get $6332$. Then they are adding $7\times 4+8\times 9=100$ and adding that (but shifted once, i.e. adding $1000$). The result is correct: $7332$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop why is that you multiply by 10 in the first two terms

Comment: What else is $78$ than $7\cdot 10 + 8$? What else is $94$ than $9\cdot 10+4$? This is the standard way to represent the actual number knowing its digits (in base $10$, must say!)

Comment: And - sorry I don't know how this can be done with bigger numbers. Say, for $3$-digit numbers, you have $9$ multiplications which ends up with a lots of pasting, shifting and adding, and it gets really unwieldy if you try to extrapolate. That is the principal reason why I was reluctant to post an _answer_ here, as I am sure there are all sorts of tricks to do fast calculation (which I don't know!), but this one doesn't seem to work well. I would prefer the standard ("column") method or just use a calculator: those don't make mistakes!

Comment: @StinkingBishop thanks for the answer sir, one more question are you familiar with manim library?

Comment: Sorry - I am not.

Comment: For bigger numbers, this reminds me of treating [multiplication as convolution](https://www.algorithm-archive.org/contents/convolutions/multiplication/multiplication.html). In your method, you choose to sum results in even columns and sum results in odd columns separately, to defer any carrying.

Comment: We do essentially the same operations in standard long multiplication, just in a slightly different sequence. Your method adds the first and fourth row of the sum (which is trivial), then the second and third rows, then you add the subtotals, whereas in the usual way we add the first two rows (writing only the sum), then the last two, and then add subtotals. Written with extra lines for exposition:\begin{align}78&\\\underline{\times\ 94}&\\32&&&8\times4\\28\phantom{0}&&&7\times4\times10\\72\phantom{0}&&&8\times9\times10\\\underline{63\phantom{00}}&&&7\times9\times100\\7332\end{align}

Comment: Written in the standard way:\begin{align}78&\\\underline{\times\ 94}&\\312&&&280+32\\\underline{702\phantom{0}}&&&(630+72)\times10\\7332\end{align}and your way:\begin{align}78&\\\underline{\times\ 94}&\\6332&&&63\times100+32\\\underline{1000}&&&(28+72)\times10\\7332\end{align}

Comment: When I want to multiply multidigit numbers mentally I start with the leftmost place of each number, so here I would say $7 \cdot 9 = 63(00)$  Then I do the next most significant ones, so $7 \cdot 4 = 28(0)$ and add that in getting $658(0)$ and $8 \cdot 9=72(0)$, adding to $7300$ and finally the ones place.  I find it easier to keep track of what is going on and you can quit partway if you are happy with an approximate answer.